# Emails Reception Delay when sent via SYMPA list

Tags: email, smtp, sympa

I have an installation with the following servers:

- server 1 that i use to send test emails through the SAP interface to a mailing list SYMPA
- SYMPA server: hosting the mailing list tool SYMPA
- SMTP relay server

I have several HOURS of delay between triggering the email from the
SAP interface in a BO server, and the reception of the email in
outlook to the email adresses « subscribed » to the sympa email list.
With the delay notification from the relay server. Some errors i deducted;

- « Failed to connect to Enterprise Manager » error in vSphere for the server i use to send the test emails and the relay server
- « Absence of the PID file for the Postfix service » when i check the status of postfix in the server hosting SYMPA. I’d like an
  idea of the potential source of this problem. And a fix if that’s
  possible.

When i send from the same SAP interface to the outlook email address directly it works. But when i send through the SYMPA list e-mail address, it arrives hours later with late notification from the relay server. I installed SMTP in the server i send test email from. Verified services, SYMPA interface configuration. Restarted SYMPA and Postfix services

Thank you.